# Success Callback on Model destroy doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Here is my jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Frankistan/dqbexhr0/1/

```
window.Wine = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "api/wines",
    defaults: {
        "id": null,
            "name": "",
            "grapes": "",
            "country": "USA",
            "region": "Wisconsin",
            "year": "",
            "description": "",
            "picture": "none.jpg"
    }
});

var WineCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Wine,
    url: "api/wines"
});
window.StartView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.template = _.template($('#start-template').html());
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template());

        return this.el;
    }
});

window.HeaderView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click .new': 'newWine'
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.template = _.template($('#header-template').html());
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        return this.el;
    },
    newWine: function () {
        debugger
        app.navigate('wines/new', true);
        return false;
    }
});

window.WineListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.on('add', this.appendNewWine, this);
        this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function () {
        _.each(this.collection.models, function (wine) {
            this.appendNewWine(wine);
        }, this);

        return this.el;
    },
    appendNewWine: function (wine) {
        var wineListItemView = new WineListItemView({
            model: wine
        }).render();
        this.$el.append(wineListItemView);
    }
});

window.WineListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    initialize: function () {
        this.template = _.template($('#wine-list-item-template').html());

        this.model.bind('destroy', this.remove, this);
        this.model.bind('change:name', this.render, this);

    },
    render: function () {
        console.log('ListItemView render: ');
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

        return this.el;
    },
    update: function () {
        console.log('actualizando nombre en la lista');
        debugger
        this.$el.find('a').text(this.model.get('name'));
    }
});

window.WineDetailView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "change input": "change",
            "click .save": "saveWine",
            "click .delete": "deleteWine"
    },
    initialize: function () {

        this.template = _.template($('#wine-details-template').html());

        this.model.bind("destroy", this.remove, this);
    },
    render: function () {
        console.log('DetailView render: ');
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

        return this.el;
    },
    saveWine: function () {
        // version 1
        var self = this;

        this.model.set({
            name: $('#name').val(),
            grapes: $('#grapes').val(),
            country: $('#country').val(),
            region: $('#region').val(),
            year: $('#year').val(),
            description: $('#description').val()
        });

        if (this.model.isNew()) {

            this.model.save({
                wait: true
            }, {
                success: function (wine, reponse, options) {
                    app.wineList.add(wine);
                    Backbone.history.navigate('wines/' + self.model.id, {
                        trigger: true
                    });

                }
            });
        } else {
            this.model.save();
        }

        return false;
    },
    deleteWine: function () {
        debugger
        var options = {
            success: function (model, response) {
                console.log('delete wine success');
                console.log(model);
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (model, response) {
                console.log('delete wine error');
                console.log(response);
            }
        };
        this.model.destroy(options);
    },
    change: function (event) {
        var target = event.target;
        console.log('changing ' + target.id + ' from: ' + target.defaultValue + ' to: ' + target.value);
    }
});
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        $('#header').html(new HeaderView().render());
    },

    routes: {
        "": "list",
            "wines/new": "newWine",
            "wines/:id": "wineDetails"
    },

    list: function () {
        this.before(function () {
            this.showView('#content', new StartView());
        });
    },

    wineDetails: function (id) {
        this.before(function () {
            var wine = this.wineList.get(id);
            this.showView('#content', new WineDetailView({
                model: wine
            }));
        });
    },

    newWine: function () {
        this.before(function () {
            this.showView('#content', new WineDetailView({
                model: new Wine()
            }));
        });
    },

    showView: function (selector, view) {
        if (this.currentView) this.currentView.close();

        $(selector).html(view.render());
        this.currentView = view;

        return view;
    },

    before: function (callback) {
        if (this.wineList) {
            if (callback) callback.call(this);
        } else {
            this.wineList = new WineCollection();
            var self = this;
            this.wineList.fetch({
                success: function (collection, response, options) {
                    var winelist = new WineListView({
                        collection: collection
                    }).render();
                    $('#sidebar').html(winelist);
                    if (callback) callback.call(self);
                }
            });
        }
    }

});

Backbone.View.prototype.close = function () {
    // console.log('Closing view ' + this);
    if (this.beforeClose) {
        this.beforeClose();
    }
    this.remove();
    this.off();
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    app = new AppRouter();
    if (!Backbone.history.started) {
        // Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });
        Backbone.history.start();
    }
});
```

everythings works fine but when I destroy a model by clicking ".delete" button, as you can see at lines from 137 to 151, the "deletewine" function is fired and although the model is deleted on the server (200 response), success callback is not fired!!

Any idea what could be the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not run your fiddle and I don’t know what is your server side code.
but i guess value returned from your server side code is not right.

it's response should be a json(any json hash). for example it can return:
 `{success: true}` maybe your code returns nothing?

you can also tell backbone not to expect any response from server:

```
deleteWine: function () {
    debugger
    var options = {
        contentType: false, 
        processData: false,
        success: function (model, response) {
            console.log('delete wine success');
            console.log(model);
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (model, response) {
            console.log('delete wine error');
            console.log(response);
        }
    };
    this.model.destroy(options);
}
```

please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305079/backbone-model-destroy-invoking-error-callback-function-even-when-it-works-fin).

Comment: Thank you very very much @samad montazeri !! . 
I have a look at that question and I've used `model.destroy({ dataType: "text", success: function(model, response) {
  console.log("success");
}}); ` based on @ccallendar response and it works because my server API doesnt' return any data. :D

Comment: BTW, You know why when I replace line 233 by line 232 the code breaks? I mean, I want clean URL's and I've read it can be only by using pushState, but it doesn't work... I'd be very grateful

Comment: i don't know much about Backbone js.(and i still don't know what is your server side code!). maybe this can help: [backbone js routers confusion pushstate true trailing slash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805068/backbone-js-routers-confusion-pushstate-true-trailing-slash)